# No module "AppName" error while running python manage.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=263xt_4mBNc&t=1335s) tutorial related to Django Rest Framework, on running `python manage.py` I am getting an error:

```
File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'languages'
```

My Project structure look like below:

(DRF) ➜  DRF tree .

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── api_example
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── languages
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

`settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'languages',
]
```

**Update**:

OK I removed `languages` from apps and now it gives the same error when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` from the root folder of the project.

Comment: OK it works ONLY when I move the `languages` app OUT of the project folder. In this `api-example`. But DRF official site says to create inside the project folder but it is not working for me.

Comment: The correct way is `api_example.languages`, I did not mention the parent folder. Should I remove this question?

Answer (score 0):

i have limited experience with django, when I was having problems with running manage.py, i got a different error, but I fixed it with *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *python manage.py migrate*. Sometimes this can even fix a problem with a unconfigured, brand new project. Kinda a shot in the dark, in case you haven't tried it yet.